# BX Slider not recalculating width on browser window size decrease

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I have a website utilizing the amazing and responsive BX Slider. Everything is working except when the browser window is resized DOWN, the BX Slider `<li>` width is not being recalculated.

My dev site is [lc.westguardsolutions.com/#work](http://lc.westguardsolutions.com/#work), feel free to poke around the code.

The BX Slider width *is* being recalculated correctly if the page is loaded at a small width and then *increased*, but not when it is decreased.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch this, I had another developer in my office help me debug this and it looks like we found the solution.

The way that BX Slider is calculating the individual slider size is taking a measurement of the parent. Because the parent is massive due to the slides being lined up next to each other, the "if" statements for measurement tell the slider that it's already smaller than that measurement, and not to resize smaller. Really, the slider *should* just measure the actual browser width to make its calculations, but that's part of a larger discussion on the stability of the logic that the author of BX Slider used to measure and apply responsiveness.

What fixed the issue in this case is to apply the "fade" mode `mode: 'fade'` in the BX Slider init. The reason this works is that in "fade" mode the slides are not lined up next to each other and `overflow: hidden`'d, they're stacked on top of each other and being shown one at a time. Therefore, the container div is resizing correctly and the BX Slider calculations are being made correctly.

I hope the author sees this and finds a way to implement a fix as I am not qualified to, and in the meantime use `mode: 'fade'` as a polyfill if you're having this issue.

Hope this helps someone else!